# Выход из цикла ввода выражения при нажатии кнопки enter

Tags: c++, калькулятор

Как сделать выход из цикла при нажатии кнопки enter?

Калькулятор, раньше работал до ввода '=', теперь хочу сделать завершение цикла ввода при нажатии \n

`x = getchar();`

`if ( x == '\n')` не работает.

```
cout << "Введите выражение" << endl << ' ' << endl;
for (i = 0; vvod[i-1] != '='; i++) {
    cin >> vvod[i];
    }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема при получении пустого выражения выходить?

Comment: А как это сделать?)

Comment: Читайте ввод построчно, потом анализируйте символы строки.

Comment: Нельзя использовать стринг(